# Get the last non blank value of a column

Tags: dax

This is my table in a Power BI Desktop model:

[image: sample data]

For each "No", I want to get the value of column "Data" that is non-blank.

For example, for "No" = 1203210:

[image: link]

That value would be 30/04/2016

And for "No" = 1202547:

[image: link]

The value would be: 31/01/2017.

Thus, the results I'm expecting are supposed to be shown on an additional calculated column using DAX:

[image: link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this calculated column solve your problem?

```
NewCol = 
var currentNo = [No]

return
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Data'[Date]),
    FILTER(
        'Data',
        'Data'[No] = currentNo && 'Data'[Class] <> BLANK()
    )
)
```

Where 'Data' if the name I gave you tour data table.